# Strategy to choose when doing Serialization and Deserialization using spring-kafka library

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, confluent-platform

I need to `Serialize` or `Deserialize` **any** type of **Java Object** may be `Integer/ String` or `<T>` or `User` or `Account` in my project. There might be **more than 1 type** I am not sure which one to use while configuring a `Kafka` `Producer` and `Consumer`.

There are `JsonSerializer` and `JsonDeserializer` and `StringSerializer/DESer` and many more types.

I have read https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#string-serde

So how do i arrive at a conclusion on which one to use ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you would use JSON for that situation, but the objects `User` etc, must be "Jackson-friendly" (no-arg CTOR etc). Another alternative is Apache Avro and the confluent (De)Serializers.

Comment: Thank you @Gary. And in what situations `String Ser/DeSer` is a appropriate one ?

Comment: When your app only sends or receives `String`s.